# run a program several times with a makefile

Tags: makefile, while-loop

I'm really a beginner and I want to build a makefile so I can later run a program several times.
e.g. Terminal Input: make loop 6

```
loop: $(BIN)
    terminalinput= $1 #e.g. the value 6
    count=0
    while [ $count -lt $terminalinput ]; do
        ./$(BIN) \
        count=$((count+1))
    done
```

I don't know how to get the terminal input and build it in the while loop. I use Ubuntu and I hope somebode can help me.

thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with make?

Comment: I want to create a makefile template wich I can use for my C programs. So I can write "make run = compile and run the program", "make val = compile and run valgrind", "make loop 5 = compile and run the program 5 times" etc. I want to try this with a makefile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can pass `make` variables via command line, e.g. `make loop LOOPS=10`.
2. You can use `ifdef` in the `Makefile` to determine whether a variable has been defined, e.g.

```sh
ifdef LOOPS
loop: prog
        for ((i=1; i <= ${LOOPS}; ++i)) do ./prog; done

.PHONY: loop
endif

prog:
        # Commands for making prog
```

Together, this might come close enough to what you want.

The above should abort with an error message
(about not knowing how to make `loop`)
if you forget to define `LOOPS` in the command line.
If instead you want to have a default value for `LOOPS`,
simply define it in the Makefile. Then there is no need for `ifdef`:

```sh
LOOPS = 10
loop: prog
        for ((i=1; i <= ${LOOPS}; ++i)) do ./prog; done

.PHONY: loop

prog:
        # Commands for making prog
```

Now, `make loop` runs `prog` 10 times, but you can still override that
using e.g. `make loop LOOPS=3`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I only fixed a thing and it worked. Really great community!

Comment: @wurya: The "thing" probably being that running `prog` ought to be done with an explicit path like `./prog`. Fixed.

Comment: And yes, the `for((...))` syntax is `bash`-specific. Same for the `$((...))`  construct in the question, so at least the answer remains within that context.

Answer (score 1):

I use gmake and must only change a little bit the answer of ccorn(thanks to you again). Because I had to write SHELL := /bin/bash in the first line of my makefile.

Now when I write `make loop l=5` in my terminal the programm runs 5 times. When I only write `make loop` the program runs 10 times (the default value).

This is my little test-makefile:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
BIN = stack
SRC = \
    stacktest.c \
    stack.c \

CC   = gcc
CFLAGS   = -g -Wall -Wextra -O3 -std=c99 -lm

OBJS = $(SRC:%.c=%.c)

all: $(BIN)

$(BIN): $(OBJS)

val: $(BIN)
    valgrind ./$(BIN)

run: $(BIN)
    ./$(BIN)

l = 10
loop: $(BIN)
    for ((i=1; i <= ${l}; ++i)) do ./$(BIN); done
```

I don't have include phony because I must first read up about that.

Thanks at all for the help! :)